# Oracle-How to exclude several non-overlapping date period from a certain period?

Tags: oracle

I have a sample data as below

```
With
RawTable as (
  Select 'A' ColA,'AA' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-10','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-23','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-02-11','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-13','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE 
    from dual union all
  Select 'A' ColA,'AA' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-10','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-23','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-02-15','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-18','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE
    from dual union all          
  Select 'A' ColA,'AA' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-10','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-23','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-02-20','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-22','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE
    from dual union all          
  Select 'B' ColA,'BB' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-20','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-01-10','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-13','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE
    from dual union all
  Select 'B' ColA,'BB' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-20','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-02-15','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-27','yyyy-mm-dd') ExcludeEDate
    from dual union all
  Select 'B' ColA,'BB' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-01','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-20','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-01-15','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-01-19','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE
    from dual union all
  Select 'C' ColA,'CC' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-09','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-12','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-02-08','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-13','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE
    from dual union all
  Select 'C' ColA,'CC' ColB,
    To_Date('2023-02-09','yyyy-mm-dd') START_DATE,To_Date('2023-02-12','yyyy-mm-dd') END_DATE,
    To_Date('2023-01-28','yyyy-mm-dd') Exclude_SDate,To_Date('2023-02-02','yyyy-mm-dd') EXCLUDE_EDATE
    from dual
          )
          
Select * from RawTable
```

[RawData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtZE4.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtZE4.jpg

I’d like to know how to remove non-overlapping date segment of ExcludeSDate~ExcludeEDate from StartDate~EndDate for each group of ColA and ColB.
Date span of StartDate~EndDate may be sliced into several segments.
And if ExcludeSDate~ExcludeEDate contain SartDate~EndDate,then final result need to exclude this group.

Each segment of ExcludeSDate~ExcludeEDtae does not overlap.
For each group of ColA and ColB, StartDate and EndDate are the same for each row of this group.

I try to list each possibilities using case when clause, but the hard part is how to group by ColA and ColB to give correct result.

The desired result is as follows:
[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KBI.jpg)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KBI.jpg

I tried to use case when expression in select clause but stuck in the problem of grouping ColA and ColB to give correct date span.

2023-02-27 Edit

To make Column names more readable, I change StartDate to Start_Date, EndDate to End_Date, ExlcudeSDate to Exclude_SDate,ExlcudeEdate to Exclude_EDate.
(SDate shorthands for Start_Date,EDate for End_Date)

Thanks dr's answer, it gives me lots of insight by making Exclude_EDate as the  new Start_Date if Exclude_EDate  cut between Start_Date and End_Date,then take Exclude_SDate of **next record** as new End_Date to complete this question.
This deals **End time** perfectly, but I found for each group of ColA and ColB,**if the 1st record of Exclucde_SDate is between Start_Date and End_Date, then the output will miss a period,** ie. from 1st record Start_Date to Exlcude_SDate.
For example if first row of Exclude_SDate changes to 2023-02-11,then a period of 2023-02-10 to 2023-02-11 is missing.
I add some queries to union dr's answer by using **Lag** Function to check if current row is the first row and if it is,then further check if Exclude_SDate is between Start_Date and End_Date.
Here's the final query.

```
Select COLA, COLB,START_DATE_2 Start_Date,END_DATE_2 END_DATE
from (
      Select COLA, COLB, START_DATE, END_DATE, Exclude_SDate, EXCLUDE_EDATE,
                CASE WHEN EXCLUDE_EDATE BETWEEN START_DATE And END_DATE 
                     THEN EXCLUDE_EDATE END "START_DATE_2",
                CASE WHEN EXCLUDE_EDATE BETWEEN START_DATE And END_DATE THEN
                    CASE WHEN LEAD(COLA) OVER(Order By COLA, START_DATE) = COLA And 
                              LEAD(COLB) OVER(Order By COLA, COLB, START_DATE) = COLB
                         THEN LEAD(Exclude_SDate) OVER(Order By COLA, COLB, START_DATE)
                    ELSE END_DATE
                    END
                END "END_DATE_2"
      From rawtable 
      --below:deal with problem that initial Exclude_SDate cut between Start_Date and End_Date
      Union all  
      Select R.COLA, R.COLB, R.START_DATE, R.END_DATE, R.Exclude_SDate, R.EXCLUDE_EDATE,
            Case When Lag(R.ColA,1,null) over(partition by R.ColA Order by R.ColA,R.START_DATE) is null And
                      Lag(R.ColB,1,null) over(partition by R.ColA,R.ColB Order by R.ColA,R.ColB,R.START_DATE) is null And
                      R.Exclude_SDate between R.Start_Date and R.End_Date
                 then R.Start_Date 
                 Else Null 
            End "START_DATE_2", 
            Case When Lag(R.ColA,1,null) over(partition by R.ColA Order by R.ColA,R.START_DATE) is null And
                      Lag(R.ColB,1,null) over(partition by R.ColA,R.ColB Order by R.ColA,R.ColB,R.START_DATE) is null And
                      R.Exclude_SDate between R.Start_Date and R.End_Date
                  then R.Exclude_SDate 
                 Else Null
            End "END_DATE_2"
      From RawTable R
      ) 
Where Start_Date_2 is not null
Order by ColA,ColB,Start_Date_2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use CASE expression with LEAD() OVER() anlytic function like here:

```sql
SELECT  COL_A, COL_B, START_DATE_2 "START_DATE", END_DATE_2 "END_DATE"
FROM (  Select 
          COL_A, COL_B, START_DATE, END_DATE, EXCLUDES_DATE, EXCLUDE_EDATE,
          CASE WHEN EXCLUDE_EDATE BETWEEN START_DATE And END_DATE THEN EXCLUDE_EDATE END "START_DATE_2",
          CASE WHEN EXCLUDE_EDATE BETWEEN START_DATE And END_DATE THEN
              CASE WHEN LEAD(COL_A) OVER(Order By COL_A, START_DATE) = COL_A And 
                        LEAD(COL_B) OVER(Order By COL_A, COL_B, START_DATE) = COL_B
                   THEN LEAD(EXCLUDES_DATE) OVER(Order By COL_A, COL_B, START_DATE)
              ELSE END_DATE
              END
          END "END_DATE_2"
        From 
          rawtable
        Order By COL_A, COL_B, START_DATE   )
Where
    START_DATE_2 Is Not Null
```

With your sample data:

| COL_A | COL_B | START_DATE | END_DATE | EXCLUDES_DATE | EXCLUDE_EDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | AA | 10-FEB-23 | 23-FEB-23 | 01-FEB-23 | 13-FEB-23 |
| A | AA | 10-FEB-23 | 23-FEB-23 | 15-FEB-23 | 18-FEB-23 |
| A | AA | 10-FEB-23 | 23-FEB-23 | 20-FEB-23 | 22-FEB-23 |
| B | BB | 01-FEB-23 | 20-FEB-23 | 10-JAN-23 | 13-FEB-23 |
| B | BB | 01-FEB-23 | 20-FEB-23 | 15-FEB-23 | 27-FEB-23 |
| B | BB | 01-FEB-23 | 20-FEB-23 | 15-JAN-23 | 19-JAN-23 |
| C | CC | 09-FEB-23 | 12-FEB-23 | 08-FEB-23 | 13-FEB-23 |
| C | CC | 09-FEB-23 | 12-FEB-23 | 28-JAN-23 | 02-FEB-23 |

... the result should be:

| COL_A | COL_B | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | AA | 13-FEB-23 | 15-FEB-23 |
| A | AA | 18-FEB-23 | 20-FEB-23 |
| A | AA | 22-FEB-23 | 23-FEB-23 |
| B | BB | 13-FEB-23 | 15-FEB-23 |

Comment: Thanks, your solution helps me a ton. But I found 1st record problem.  I edited the post. By referecing lead function, I use lag function to fix the 1st record issue.

Comment: @jouyungcheng You are welcome. Sorry I'didn't think about the 1st row problem but you get it right yourself and did the adjustments - which is even better. Congrats...